# worst case for this code?

Tags: c++, big-o, time-complexity

```
n = 0;
sum = 0;
cin >> x;
while (x != -999) 
{
    n++;
    sum += x;
    cin >> x;
}
mean = sum / n;
```

I understand how to find complexity of an algorithm.
My problem is that I'm not sure if this can be solved since it relies on input.
For the worst case, I think that the input never equals -999 so the worst case complexity is infinity. 
Is this the right way to go about this? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: The time taken to execute this algorithm scales linearly with the number of inputs. If there are infinite inputs (never -999) then it takes infinite time. But it's still O(n).

Comment: @Blorgbeard I think it's incorrect to talk about "infinite inputs" for this matter.

Comment: @Columbo why is that?

Comment: @Blorgbeard Because it seems that there can't be an infinitely large input. Why not just say "If the input doesn't end, neither does the algorithm"?

Comment: @Columbo those words mean the same as the ones I said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The time taken to execute this algorithm scales linearly with the number of inputs. If there are infinite inputs (never -999) then it takes infinite time. But it's still O(n).

Comment: I upvoted this. If I could have been bothered answering, I would have.

Answer (score -1):

You're right it's not possible to solve this. In this case I would say that it's **best case scenario** if your input ever fullfills the condition. In most cases loop will go forever , even if you include variable overflow there are little chances for `x` to be equal to `-999` (and by overflow i mean case when user inputs very large number that is then parsed to negative number).

For the sake of complexity theory the running time of this algorith is `O(k)` where `k` stands for the number of times the loops is executed. And is good to assume it's infinity.